# Decrease vertical space between fields | Custom Sharepoint Form

Tags: sharepoint-designer, form

Good Morning;

I am using Sharepoint 2013 OP with SPD 2013.

How do you decrease the amount of vertical space between 2 fields on a Sharepoint Custom Form?

I have created the form using SPD2013, and inserted it onto a blank .aspx page. There is a considerable amount of vertical space between each field. Thanks

Comment: can you add may be a screenshot to understand this better..you can use dev tools and inspect element and check whats causing this

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to adjust the spacing with infopath.  The edit and new forms are linked and can be edited either with html or graphically.